# Chinese Tourist Visa was stamped on observation page?

Tags: visas, passports, passport-stamps

I just picked up my passport today at the Chinese Consulate, and realized my visa was stamped on one of the three observation pages on my passport after I came home. I'm not sure whether I need to get a new passport and ask them to reissue the visa. Has anyone experienced this situation before?